# Can't disable messages for pymc3.find_MAP()

Tags: pymc3

Sorry for the dumb question but I am unable to find any way to disable messages for pymc3.find_MAP(). As someone new to PyMC3 I think I've just learned to use the syntax properly (shakily) to do a single MAP estimate, given prior and likelihood functions. I'm about to try and scale this up to process a large number of variables but to so I'd like to eliminate messages of the type that I'm getting, e.g.:

> Optimization terminated successfully.
>
> ```
>  Current function value: 1.889038
>
>  Iterations:2
>
>  Function evaluations: 4
>
>  Gradient evaluations: 4
> ```

but can't find anything in the documentation indicating how to do so. I figure I can turn them back on when I need to debug. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Extra arguments are passed into the optimization function, which by default is from `scipy.optimize.*`, so passing `disp=False` to `pm.find_MAP` will suppress messages.

As an aside, `find_MAP` is no longer recommended to initialize sampling.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that, but went back and tried as per your suggestion and it worked. Much appreciated.